# Javascript - how to pass value into javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to get value into javascript and pass it to alert.  Here is the code that I use to pass the value....

```
        <img onclick="handpost()" id="colorface" name="red" src="http://www.asl-ela.org/image/redface.png" alt="Red face" /></a>
```

Then I use function to get the data from img tag....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function handpost()  {
      var color = document.getElementById('colorface').name;
      alert(color);
   }
</script>
```

I keep getting alert box saying undefined.  What does that mean?!?!?!

Comment: `name` is not an `<img>` property

Comment: Since `name` is a property of img element. You should use `getAttribute` to get its value, try this `document.getElementById('colorface').getAttribute('name')`

Comment: Since `name` is not a standard property on `img` attributes, you shouldn't use it.  Instead, it is better to use `data-name` as the whole `data-*` realm as been reserved for custom values.     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes .. these values can also be accessed via jQuery's `data` method or `getAttribute('data-name')`

Answer (score 9):

It means exactly what it reads: `document.getElementById('colorface').name` is undefined. `document.getElementById('colorface')` may exist but it doesn't have property `name`. Try `document.getElementById('colorface').getAttribute('name')`.
`name` is not standard attribute of `img` but if you add it then you can access it.
[image]

Comment: I changed `name` to `.getAttribute('name')` and it works.

Comment: Hi Alex, I did use the code that you suggested.  I tried it and the alert box says null.  I tried it in jfiddle and it works as it says red.  So what is going on?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the following instead :

```
var color = document.getElementById('colorface').getAttribute('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how could you get it as `undefined`

> **Element.name**, `name` gets or sets the name property of a DOM object; it only applies to the following elements: `<a>`, `<applet>`, `<button>`, `<form>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<map>`, `<meta>`, `<object>`, `<param>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`([From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name))

```js
function handpost() {
  var color = document.getElementById('colorface').name;
  alert(color);
}
```

```html
<img onclick="handpost()" id="colorface" name="red" src="http://www.asl-ela.org/image/redface.png" alt="Red face" />
```